# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h' and 'ctype.h'

Tags: build, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn, nant

I'm trying to build *TortoiseSVN* and when I run *nant* setup, I get these build errors and I'm not sure how to resolve them. There are similar posts on SO but they're outdated or do not apply to my situation. Eventually, I will need to use Visual Studio 2015 to build the project.

Here's the build error from the log:

```
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\dir.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\filepath.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\filestat.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\network_io\unix\sockaddr.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\atomic\win32\apr_atomic.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\locks\win32\proc_mutex.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\encoding\apr_escape.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\windows.h(160) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\filesys.c)

[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\dir.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\locks\win32\proc_mutex.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\filepath.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\filestat.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\network_io\unix\sockaddr.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\atomic\win32\apr_atomic.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\file_io\win32\filesys.c)
[build cl] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\~\Desktop\SVN\TortoiseSVN192\ext\apr\encoding\apr_escape.c)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258311/cannot-open-include-file-ctype-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the Header file here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\km\crt\excpt.h
```

So add the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\km\crt\` to the search for includes files in the project properties.

If you use the Win10 SDK (for Version 1511), it it located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\km\crt\excpt.h
```

Comment: okay I got it working but the problem is now it can't find ctype.h. Do you have that file?

Comment: yes, in the same CRT folders: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\km\crt\ctype.h" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\ctype.h"

Comment: hmm okay, mine is a little different but I did find the ctype.h. Now when you say, add the path to the search for include files, what do you mean? Where? Btw, I couldn't find the path under Windows Kits\8.1 ... only Windows Kits\10

Comment: Here is explained what I mean with the INCLUDE settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx

Comment: Okay thanks. I added the path to the INCLUDE and EXE directories under VC++ Directories but same error hmm... Can I add the path a different way? It might be because I have multiple projects under one solution? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: hm, this is strange. Why do you want to compile TSVN on your own? If you have a bug that was fixed in the code, install the latest nightly: https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/1.9.x/

Comment: No, I need it build on my own because I need to integrate a new feature into TortoiseSVN. So I have to build it

Comment: ok, follow the steps from this file: http://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/build.txt

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been using. I just copied and pasted the contents from Windows Kit\10\ to Windows Kit\8.1\ and that fixed most of the errors. One more error on "The object file was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries". Thanks for your help btw!