# Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed c++ package on VS 2015 , if I tried to build the project ,the following problem appears :

C1083   Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory  Win32Project5   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h  31

Any possible solution ....

Comment: Does https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04a10aec-3242-4e01-af3f-cb1881d71358/cannot-compile-windows-universal-dll-or-win32-dll-with-vs2015-rc-cannot-open-include-file-ctypeh?forum=vcgeneral help?

Comment: What project are you trying to build? Post project properties and the include directories of your config...

Comment: I found the 'ctype.h' file and included the directory to the project , the problem has gone , but i'm getting another problem : cannot open file uctrd.lib

Comment: In my case this was because of WDK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35927499/3092609

Answer (score 27):

Repair / Reinstall visual studio.
Make sure that the Windows SDK option (Probably 8.1 in your case) is ticked,
As you can see in this picture:
[image]

Comment: If this works, just.. wow. `ctype.h` has *nothing* to do with Windows or its SDK. It's part of the C standard library (likewise, `ctype` as the C++ counterpart). If anything, I would expect something broken in Programming Languages, not the Windows SDK configuration. Or is this in relation to the *second* question this post has now morphed to?

Comment: I've searched for ctype.h, It's located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt, which is the directory that's created when you install the SDK..

Comment: Reinstall whole Visual Studio just to add 1 feature, that i forgot to tick, really?

Comment: Why would you think you have to reinstall? That's the interface to add or remove features. It's under Modify in Add/Remove or you can run vs_setup.exe.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 it is in component called Windows Universal CRT SDK and you can find it in Compilators section under component installation tab.

Comment: Wow, 8 GB just to add [support for the C++ language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31953769/393280) and this to my existing bloated Visual Studio install.

Comment: ctype.h is in fact located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt"

Comment: Windows Universal CRT SDK requires additional 155 MiB in VS 2022

Answer (score 10):

To add the missing component, go to **Control Panel** -> **Uninstall a Program**, and select to Change the installation of Visual Studio.
Then, here is the option you need to check:
[image]
Then press "Modify".

Also don't forget to update the project's Properties to be using Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0.
[image]

Comment: Changing the SDK Version to Windows 10 does not fix the root cause of the problem. If you need to compile a program to run on older versions of windows, the SDK must be set to 7.0. And if you solely install windows 7/8 SDK, the project will run into this error while compiling. 

To solve this the user must also install Windows 10 SDK, then the missing files are added to the path. This is a M$ mistake, since they only include the missing header files in the latest windows SDKs (10 and 11).

Answer (score 6):

Right click on your solution or project in the solution explorer
& Retarget your solution or project to the installed SDK version

Answer (score 2):

Here is mine VS 2017 build tools configuration to make Python 3.7 and up to compile on my local machine and fix. Please notice that MS changed VS Studio Build Tools interface

[image: VS Build Tool 2017 configuration for pyodbc compilation]

In order to make code to compile you also MUST to install [ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

You can download VS 2017 Build tools from:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

[image: VS Build Tool 2017 download]