# fail to build boost 1.68 for visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I am trying to build boost library for visual studio 2017. I follow the following steps
1. Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017
2. Go to the boost folder
3. use bootstrap.bat

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.

The log says

```
d:\boost_1.68_zip\boost_1_68_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(71): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory
compile.c
d:\boost_1.68_zip\boost_1_68_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(71): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory
constants.c
debug.c
d:\boost_1.68_zip\boost_1_68_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(71): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory
...
...
...
```

I have search around on stack overflow and try to solve the problem, but none seems to work (I tried install different sdk, universal crt etc.)

I manage to have a work around by manually set the INCLUDE and LIB variable by the following

```
INCLUDE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;
LIB
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86;
```

It could successfully get the b2.exe.

However, when I build the library using
b2 --target=shared, static

Most library still files and it says fatal errors, cannot find some h file or lib file.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should be asking the Boost guys

Comment: Did you go through [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258311/cannot-open-include-file-ctype-h-no-such-file-or-directory) It would have to be the paths from Microsoft that are the issue.

Comment: Yes, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using a new computer, using the default setting to install Visual Studio 2017 Community version. It compiles fine.