# Unable to install Snakemake in either command prompt nor anaconda prompt

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda, snakemake

I'm trying to install Snakemake.

When I try to use pip, I receive the following error message:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ANGELA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1kbp7voq\\datrie\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANGELA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_eliva3i\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
ERROR: running install
running build
running build_clib
building 'libdatrie' library
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\libdatrie
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\libdatrie\datrie
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilibdatrie "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" /Tclibdatrie\datrie\alpha-map.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\libdatrie\datrie\alpha-map.obj
alpha-map.c
libdatrie\datrie\alpha-map.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ANGELA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1kbp7voq\\datrie\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANGELA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_eliva3i\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ANGELA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1kbp7voq\datrie\
```

I've downloaded C++ and python build tools for MS Visual studio 2019. I've also upgraded setup tools.

When I try to install using the anaconda prompt, I get this:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

 > - snakemake -> pygraphviz
```

`conda install pygraphviz` also yields the same message, and I've appended conda-forge to the channels.

Comment: As far as I know, there is currently an issue related to the datrie package that makes snakemake uninstallable with pip under python 3.7: https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/934/installation-failed-in-python-37

Answer (score 0):

`conda install -c bioconda snakemake`

The package is in the `bioconda` channel. It's good practice to hit up https://anaconda.org/ and search for any new packages you want to install since the website will actually tell you in which channel the package is.

Comment: It's not going to solve the problem. All Anaconda `snakemake` builds require `pygraphviz` which is not available for `win-64` platform on any standard channels.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't read the pip error log carefully enough to realize it is a windows system. I'm going to leave the answer here anyway, since a) bioconda is the correct channel for that package and b) searching on anaconda.org will also show the OSs the package is available for.

Answer (score 0):

## PyPI

The `pip` error has some related questions (e.g., [Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42258311/570918)), but I didn't see any VS2019-specific solutions. And the older solutions seem to have various causes, which sounds like a mess to me.

## Conda

I'd still try the Conda route.  The issue here is that the default Snakemake build requires `pygraphviz` and that's not available for **win-64** platform through any of your channels.

#### No Graphviz

The easiest alternative is to opt for the `snakemake-minimal` package instead, which doesn't have the `pygraphviz` dependency. The only thing Snakemake uses Graphviz for is to generate DAG plots, which in my experience is practically useless for anything but rather trivial pipelines anyway. [The minimal version](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/snakemake-minimal) also leaves out remote file support (e.g., DropBox interfacing) and fancy report generation. So, if you just need core functionality, then run

```
conda install snakemake-minimal
```

(I'm assuming you already have Bioconda + Conda Forge channels.)

#### Graphviz

If you really want the Graphviz plot or other extras, you could try something like

```
conda activate
conda install graphviz pip
pip install pygraphviz
conda install snakemake
```

That is, make sure to use the `pip` *in your Conda env*, and only use it to install `pygraphviz`.  However, using both PyPI and Conda [can lead to an unstable env](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/).

There are some user channels on Anaconda Cloud that have **win-64** builds of `pygraphviz`, but I do not recommend sourcing from random user channels unless you trust them.

Answer (score 0):

According  to [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/934/installation-failed-in-python-37), snakemake cannot currently be installed right away using pip under python3.7. It's dependency `datrie` cannot be installed automatically.

On the issue discussion, there is a suggested workaround: first installing `datrie` from git, then `snakemake`:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/pytries/datrie.git
pip3 install snakemake
```

Answer (score 0):

**See https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/246**

This is **not a bug with snakemake**, but a known issue with [`datrie`](https://github.com/pytries/datrie/issues/73). There is a [PR](https://github.com/pytries/datrie/pull/76) currently open which solves this problem, but until it is merged, the following solutions should work.

A [previous issue on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/934/installation-failed-in-python-37) has dealt with this for python3.7.

### Workaround

#### Python3.7

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/pytries/datrie.git
pip3 install snakemake
```

#### Python3.8

```
pip3 install "git+https://github.com/ashwinvis/datrie.git@python3.8"
pip3 install snakemake
```

Answer (score -2):

The error shows that the package you are trying to install uses Microsoft VCC compiler

```
 No such file or directory error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 to solve this issue

Comment: That is the version of Visual Studio I installed.

Comment: This is not a solution.