# Building boost.build engine

Tags: boost

F:\boost_1_72_0>bootstrap
Building Boost.Build engine
File Not Found

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.

'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
F:\boost_1_72_0>

Answer (score 0):

same here

Building Boost.Build engine
File Not Found

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.

Than, I checked the bootstrap.log and see fatal c1083 error for every file

from this solution;
[Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258311/cannot-open-include-file-ctype-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

I modified visual studio and add "windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)"

and got this;

Building Boost.Build engine

Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam for msvc...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

```
.\b2
```

Well, I think this command is for linux and doesnt work on cmd
and b2 is an exe file. So, I just click on it :)) will see,