# Problem with Building Boost Library : Boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I was trying to follow the tutorial instructions on https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/more/getting_started/windows.html.

> 5.1   Simplified Build From Source
> If you wish to build from source with Visual C++, you can use a simple build procedure described in this section. Open the command prompt and change your current directory to the Boost root directory. Then, type the following commands:
> bootstrap
> .\b2

I get a whole list of errors after running the following command `C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0> .\bootstrap`in the Visual Studio Terminal.

May I know what the issue is?

Thank you very much.

```
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local
could not find "vswhere"
could not find "vswhere"
###
### Using 'vc142' toolset.
###

C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine>"cl" /nologo /MP /MT /TP /Feb2 /wd4996 /O2 /GL /EHsc   -DNDEBUG  builtins.cpp class.cpp command.cpp compile.cpp constants.cpp cwd.cpp debug.cpp debugger.cpp execcmd.cpp execnt.cpp execunix.cpp filent.cpp filesys.cpp fileunix.cpp frames.cpp function.cpp glob.cpp hash.cpp hcache.cpp hdrmacro.cpp headers.cpp jam.cpp jamgram.cpp lists.cpp make.cpp make1.cpp md5.cpp mem.cpp modules.cpp native.cpp object.cpp option.cpp output.cpp parse.cpp pathnt.cpp pathsys.cpp pathunix.cpp regexp.cpp rules.cpp scan.cpp search.cpp jam_strings.cpp startup.cpp subst.cpp sysinfo.cpp timestamp.cpp variable.cpp w32_getreg.cpp modules/order.cpp modules/path.cpp modules/property-set.cpp modules/regex.cpp modules/sequence.cpp modules/set.cpp /link kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib
builtins.cpp
class.cpp
command.cpp
compile.cpp
constants.cpp
cwd.cpp
debug.cpp
debugger.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file builtins.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file compile.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file class.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file command.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file debug.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file cwd.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file constants.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file debugger.cpp)
execcmd.cpp
execnt.cpp
execunix.cpp
filent.cpp
filesys.cpp
fileunix.cpp
frames.cpp
function.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file execcmd.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file filent.cpp)
glob.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file execunix.cpp)
hash.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file filesys.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file execnt.cpp)
hcache.cpp
hdrmacro.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file fileunix.cpp)
headers.cpp
jam.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file function.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file frames.cpp)
jamgram.cpp
lists.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file glob.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file hash.cpp)
make.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file hdrmacro.cpp)
make1.cpp
md5.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file jam.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file hcache.cpp)
mem.cpp
modules.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file headers.cpp)
native.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file jamgram.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file make1.cpp)
object.cpp
option.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file lists.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\md5.h(53): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file md5.cpp)
output.cpp
parse.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file modules.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file make.cpp)
pathnt.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file mem.cpp)
pathsys.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file native.cpp)
pathunix.cpp
regexp.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file option.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file output.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file object.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file parse.cpp)
rules.cpp
scan.cpp
search.cpp
jam_strings.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file pathsys.cpp)
startup.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file pathunix.cpp)
subst.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file pathnt.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file rules.cpp)
sysinfo.cpp
timestamp.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file jam_strings.cpp)
variable.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file regexp.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file startup.cpp)
w32_getreg.cpp
order.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file scan.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file subst.cpp)
path.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file search.cpp)
property-set.cpp
regex.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file timestamp.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file sysinfo.cpp)
sequence.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file variable.cpp)
set.cpp
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(73): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file w32_getreg.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file modules/path.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file modules/property-set.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file modules/order.cpp)
C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine\modules\../mem.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file modules/regex.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file modules/set.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file modules/sequence.cpp)

C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine>dir *.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 8A6F-B88B

 Directory of C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine

File Not Found

C:\sdk\boost_1_77_0\tools\build\src\engine>copy /b .\b2.exe .\bjam.exe
The system cannot find the file specified.

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
```

Comment: Possible relevant: [Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258311/cannot-open-include-file-ctype-h-no-such-file-or-directory#42258579)

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? The fact that it can't find vswhere is odd if you're using 2019 as indicated by `Using 'vc142' toolset`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Hi, It's Visual Studio 2019. I'm just pointing it out because I can't seem to get it to build. I've tried looking on Google and I've run from cmd and VS terminal. So, I'm curious as to why it won't work.

I've skipped ahead and the other steps work but I just can't get over why I can't build the files.